# Shortcode return function with link href inside PHP

Tags: php, functions, links

I'm trying to write a shortcode in function.php with a link to share the current page in Twitter. However this link contains some PHP in the href and I can't figure it out how to make it work. Here is the code:

```
add_shortcode ( "indice", "indice_output" );
function indice_output( $atts, $content="null" ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        '' => ''
    ), $atts ));

    return '<div class="boxed max-width"><div class="indice-title"><span>' . $content . '</span><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div>';

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you add how you're using this shortcode? What are you putting between the shortcode tags?

Comment: Thank you for responding! But Nuno Sarmento just found the answer with ob_start and ob_clean to print the HTML inside the shortcode.

Comment: What if I insert `eval('Delete the entire WordPress installation');` into a link? Your website might have the potential to be hacked in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ob_start and ob_get_clean to print out your shortcode.

```
function shortcode_html()

     ob_start(); ?>

    <div class="boxed max-width">
        <div class="indice-title">
            <span><?php echo $content; ?></span>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div> <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'print_shortcode', 'shortcode_html' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly, I actually didn't know about ob_start and ob_clean. Be sure I'll be using it for next project. I just added in the code

`function shortcode_html($atts, $content="null")` to print the content.